# Update / run code while typing in text field [Swift / iOS]

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, ipad

I'm making a basic app for iOS, and I was hoping somebody would be able to help me.

Basically the app takes numbers from text fields and enters them into a formula which is output to a label. This calculation is performed when I tap a button.

Is there a way to automatically calculate this after every keypress/number entered, so I don't have to press the "Calculate" button every time?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add method for editing changed

Interface builder by right-clicking on the `UITextField` and dragging the "Editing Changed"

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That was very easy and worked! Can't believe I couldn't find it by searching.

Answer (score 0):

```
[textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged]
```

Add your code inside the `textDidChange:` method.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that adding target for

> UIControlEventEditingChanged

event is correct way but you may also subscribe for

> UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification

and handle all text changes from there.